# Stemmer in Solr

Tags: apache, solr, solrj, stemming

I was using the EnglishPorterFilterFactory  for the application that I'm currently building in solr. Things are going fine. I tried using EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory  since I wanted to go for a less aggressive one. But I was not able to analyze the huge difference in the solr results. Whats the difference between the both? Also could you recommend me a less aggressive filter factory for pluralization stemming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for the HunspellStemFilterFactory. Given that it is based on dictionaries rather than algorithms, I expect it to be less aggressive.

Comment: Could you please let me know the difference between  EnglishPorterFilterFactory  and  EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory ?

Comment: They implement algorithms described by different research papers. See http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/ and http://www.medialab.tfe.umu.se/courses/mdm0506a/material/fulltext_ID%3D10049387%26PLACEBO%3DIE.pdf (look for "S stemmer")